# Map in Dart is replacing the values of previous keys with the last updated value

Tags: dart

I am actually working with `map`s in Dart and I couldn't figure out why the `map` variable in my example is behaving strangely or I am doing something wrong in my code.

Please can someone help me to debug the code, I have posted the code to reproduce the issue.

> example.dart

```
void main() {
  var data2 = {};
  var data1 = {};

  var floorDetails = new Map();
  floorDetails.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    data2.clear();
    data1.clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      data1 = {
        'flat${(i + 1) * 100 + (j + 1)}': {'flattype': "flat"},
      };
      data2.addAll(data1);
    }
    print('data2=$data2');

    floorDetails['floor${(i+1)}'] = data2;

    print('floorDetails = $floorDetails');
  }

  print(floorDetails.keys);
}
```

The output from the code is:

```
floorDetails = {
  floor1: {
    flat201: {flattype: flat}, 
    flat202: {flattype: flat}
  },
  floor2: {
    flat201: {flattype: flat},
    flat202: {flattype: flat}
  }
}
```

Actually I was expecting the output to be:

```
floorDetails = {
  floor1: {
    flat101: {flattype: flat},
    flat102: {flattype: flat}
  }, 
  floor2: {
    flat201: {flattype: flat}, 
    flat202: {flattype: flat}
  }
}
```

this is actually overwriting the values of all the keys inside the `map` `floorDetails` as per documentation for `Map.addAll()` method

> ```
> void addAll(
>   Map<K, V> other
> )
> ```
>
> Adds all key-value pairs of other to this map.
>
> If a key of other is already in this map, its value is overwritten.
>
> The operation is equivalent to doing `this[key] = value` for each key and associated value in other. It iterates over other, which must therefore not change during the iteration.

although in the given example the keys are different but it is still overwriting the values.

Please, any help would be much appreciated.
Many Thanks,
Mahi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first iteration, here you assign `data2`

```
floorDetails['floor${(i+1)}'] = data2;
```

but the first line in the next iteration is

```
data2.clear();
```

which clears `data2`. This also clears the content of floorDetails['floor1']`, because it references the same map.

Either you create a new map, instead of clearing it by changing

```
data2.clear();
data1.clear();
```

to

```
data2 = {}; // or new Map()
data1 = {};
```

or create a copy of the map before assigning it

```
floorDetails['floor${(i+1)}'] = new Map.from(data2);
```

Map is an object and copied by reference. Only primitive types like `bool`, `double`, `int`, and `String` are copied by value.

Comment: Or you could use `new Map.from(data2)` instead of `{}..addAll(data2)`.

Comment: Right, that's better.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing thank you very much @Günter Zöchbauer you have saved me a lot of time as I was trying to figure out what was wrong for quite a long time.

Comment: You're welcome :-). Glad to hear this worked for you.